# .NET Data Model is shown as XML and not as Diagram

Tags: c#, model, entity, diagram, edmx

That is. I format my computer and install the entire enviroment again, but I can't see the data model diagram.
I mean, I open the data model (edmx file) and I see all the DB tables and DB information in an XML file. Not the diagram.

I installed vs2010 sp1, net framework 4, micro net framework 4.1, entity framework 4.1

I don't know what I am missing. Can you help me?

Without that I cannot update the model.

Is seems easy but I don't know how to solve it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you open the EDMX file in the solution explorer of Visual Studio with "Right-Mouse-Click->Open With..." ...

[image]

...what do you see in the following dialog? It should be like this:

[image]

If looks like in your case the "default" (= format when you just double click on the EDMX file) is one of the XML editors. It should be "ADO.NET Entity Data Model Designer". You can make it the default by selecting the line in the list box and then click on "Set as Default" on the right side.

Comment: Thanks for the mini tutorial! It will be very helpful.-
I tried that but I found that I dont have the ADO.NET option in that box. Which app I need to instal to see that option?

Comment: @Faabass: That's strange. I thought the model designer will always automatically installed with Visual Studio. I'm sorry but I don't know what is missing. I suggest that you create a new question to ask how to install the Model designer.

Comment: That was the problem, the ADO.NET Model was not installed in my VS. I have to reinstall the program to install the ADO.NET, and then I have to do what you told me.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

download and install .NET framework 4.8 helps me.