# How add ADO.net entity model framework to Visual Studio 2017 to connect Oracle DB?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio

Within Visual Studio 2017 there is no ADO.net Entity model in 'Add New Item' menu?
It is available on previous versions of Visual Studio. What kind of solution can fix that problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't find ADO.net Entity Data Model template in VS2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44299332/cant-find-ado-net-entity-data-model-template-in-vs2017)

Comment: If nothing helps as per the link. try repair for VS.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you are useing visual studio 2017, use **ADO.NET Entity Data Model** to use new facilities.
[Visual Studio.NET 2017, ADO.NET Entity Data Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9d7de.jpg)

Comment: Thar ADO.NET Entity Model option does not display in that menu.