# WebCore I cannot use Entity Framework to generate models from DB

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

I have Entity Framework installed (6.2), but I cannot find the option to create models from db automatically, as in this tutorial:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/database-first-development/creating-the-web-application

When I click "Add new Item" and I look in data I do not have the item required in the list: "ADO.NET Entity Data Model"

Answer (score -1):

Try use the Search box on the top-right corner of the Add New Item window.

If it can't find the "ADO.NET Entity Data Model" item, you can try another way with brute force - reinstalling Visual Studio.

Comment: The search cannot find. That's not an option. Also I have the item showing when I am using a Dot net forms application, but not in webcore

Comment: How about the solutions to this question? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44299332/cant-find-ado-net-entity-data-model-template-in-vs2017