# Can't Add ADO.NET Entity Data Model to .NET Core 2.1 Project

Tags: visual-studio, entity-framework, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

### The Issue...

As the title states, I've installed the [.NET Core 2.1 SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/windows) and created a new .NET Core 2.1 project. When I go to **Project > Add Item... > Data**, I do not have the **ADO.NET Entity Data Model** option.

I am using *Visual Studio 2017 15.7.3*, which I've installed only hours ago.

The Error and Warning logs are clean.

Any assistance is appreciated.

---

### What I've done so far...

- Researched. You'll notice I've pulled most of my attempts to solve this issue from primarily these three resources:

  - [StackOverflow: Can't find ADO.net Entity Data Model template in VS 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44299332/cant-find-ado-net-entity-data-model-template-in-vs2017) <sup>(This question is pre-2.1 and has no accepted answer, so I feel this deserves an updated discussion)</sup>
  - [Microsoft: Announcing Entity Framework Core 2.0](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/08/14/announcing-entity-framework-core-2-0/)
  - [Microsoft Docs: Getting Started with EF Core on ASP.NET Core with an Existing Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/aspnetcore/existing-db)
- Ensured that *Entity Framework 6 Tools* is included in my VS installation
- Added the following dependencies...

  - NuGet

    - Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore (2.1.0)
    - Microsoft.EntityFrameWorkCore.Relational (2.1.0)
    - Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer (2.1.0)
    - Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools (2.1.0)
    - Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design (2.1.0)
  - SDK

    - Microsoft.NETCore.App (2.1.0)
    - NETStandard.Library (2.0.3)
- Build / Rebuild / Clean / Restart Visual Studio / Restart PC

Answer (score 16, accepted):

EntityFramework Core doesn't use the "EDMX" data model designers, it is purely code-first.

See the [Getting Started with EF Core on ASP.NET Core with an Existing Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/aspnetcore/existing-db) to scaffold a database context from an existing database or create a new model and use migrations to create and update databases.

**Update**: In .NET Core 3.0, you will be able to use Entity Framework 6 along with .edmx models (which may require VS 2019)

Comment: Ahh I had read that page, however wanted to stick with what I knew and so I glazed over the scaffolding portion, although I *did* grab `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design (2.1.0)`. Knowing that I don't have much of an option, I suppose I'll end up going that route. Thanks!

Comment: Hmmm... So I've done some reading, and while I was able to confirm that EntityFramework Core does not use `EDMX` files just as you've stated, from what I've read it sounds like the Add Items dialog *should* still give me the *Entity Data Model* option, however it would simply add the class files instead of the EDMX. In any event, I'm fine using the scaffolding solution. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Even if you do that, there’s some tooling missing to build and embed the model in the correct way and designer support is fragile at best on the new project system. For the core 3.0 Timeline, plans for a new version of classic EF (6.3) for .net core were announced

Comment: Personally I suggest moving to code-first since it makes developing and migrations easier

Comment: I appreciate the insight. I'm implementing this in a personal pet-project with the goal to learn a few new frameworks and such, so going the alternative route of code-first may just be perfect. Thanks Martin.

Comment: Still can't see Ado data entity model in visual studio 2019 with Asp >Net Core 3.00 project. What have to do? Is there a way?

Comment: Since the introduction of Source Generators, I guess one can create an option for edmx to be used, but only as an "AdditionalFile" that a source generator would then read and then generate the code how the .NET Framework's ADO.NET templated did it previously. This would require knowing the ins and outs of Roslyn however (which is used internally in Visual Studio as well naturally).

However I would do a different format instead, probably yaml based to make it simple to create/update using the IDE text editor.